# Why is my laptop not using the new Firefox menu layout?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, gnome-classic

On my desktop computer, Firefox has the new, more compact menu, where all menus are collapsed under where it says "Firefox", and the tabs are beside it:

[image: new firefox]

But on my laptop, it's still using the older style:

[image: old firefox]

Both are using Ubuntu 11.10. Both are Firefox 9.0.1. Both are using Gnome-Classic.

The only difference is that the laptop has Compiz effects turned off, and the desktop has Compiz effects turned on. But that couldn't make the difference... could it?

How do I get my laptop to show the new, more compact, Firefox layout?

Comment: View>Uncheck Show Menu toolbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click somewhere near and outside the address bar and uncheck the Menu Toolbar.

Comment: Doh! Clearly I was overthinking the matter. On my desktop, it seemed to switch to that automatically, so I assumed it was a version issue and looked in all the wrong places. Live and learn. :)